# Trying to run Dr Racket Files in atom editor

Tags: racket, atom-editor

I downloaded the atom text editor and the Dr Racket language support and script add ons. I am trying to run a basic file with easy expressions as such

```
(+ 3 4)
(* (* 4 4) (* 3 3))
```

however the code editor returns an error saying that racket isnt recognized

I tried to add Dr Racket to my system variables by putting the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\Racket
```

I am still getting the error thrown though.

Maybe I am in the wrong folder?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The full path is not visible above.

Comment: Edited main question with correct path

Comment: Never mind, got it working. I guess I had to initiate atom through the command prompt. Which seems like a weird solution to this problem.

Comment: Its _probably_ because the way you are adding DrRacket to your path is only run in command prompt windows.